# Save also empty fields in a list

Tags: c#

Hi have this code and I want to read items from a database for example (row number and name) and assign them in a list. The problem is that if I have NULL fields, it doesn't save me anything in the list. The point is that I would also like to save empty fields in the list for example:

ROWNUM     NAME

1        fabio

2 NULL

3 mark

4 NULL

```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<column> attributo = new List<column>();
        int totalrecordnumber = 0;
        try
        {
            using (OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(connectionString))
            using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("SELECT row_number() over (ORDER BY (NULL))," +attributecompleteness.c + " FROM " + elencocaratteristiche.completenesstable + "", conn))

            {
                conn.Open();
                using (OracleDataReader read = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (read.Read())
                    {
                        //mi salvo tutti i nomi prelevati dal database in una lista
                        attributo.Add(new column()
                        {
                            id = read.GetInt32(0),
                            nome = read.GetString(1)
                        }); ;
                        //Add(read.GetString(0));
                        //conto le righe
                        totalrecordnumber++;

                    }
                    foreach (var i in attributo)
                    {
                        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(i.id + " " + i.nome);

                    }
                }
            }

        }
        catch (Exception) { }
    }
```

Comment: the question is, what is being returned by the DB in this case. YOu need to step through that inner loop

Comment: Step one: remove the `catch (Exception) {}` handler that silently suppresses errors, so you can actually see what's going wrong -- a handler like this is *never* a good idea, at the very least print the exception details. Step 2: fix the bug you have -- hint: `DataReader` has an `IsDBNull` method. Step 3: throw all of this code away and use Dapper for boilerplate stuff like this.

Comment: @pm100 from db is being returned what you see in the example in this case

Comment: @JeroenMostert ah yes I missed that. Almost certainly that `GetString(1)` is failing.